# use Google Translate in GWT project

Tags: gwt, google-translate

I've created a project in Google Web Toolkit 2.4. Many of the the elements in my web page are created with GWT (buttons,treeItems etc).

Is there a way to use Google Translate in order to do the translation? Is there an API for Google Web Toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/LanguageGettingStarted

Comment: thnx. I've seen this, but it is deprecated. It is quite "risky" to use it